# unable to cover test cases in Junit?

Tags: java

I tried to understand Junit and eclEmma by writing a unit test for Stack methods, push(), pop() and peak().
But all of them failed.   It seems that none of them got covered. I thought initially it was a syntactical issue with my codes in how to push an integer object onto the stack but it seems that it is not the issue.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackMethodTesting {
    private Stack<Integer> aStackOfInt;

    @Before
    public void initialize()
    {
        aStackOfInt = new Stack<Integer>();
        System.out.println(" a new Stack");
    }

    @Test
    public void testpush() {
        aStackOfInt.push(new Integer(1));
        assertEquals(true,aStackOfInt.peek().equals(new Integer(1)));
    }
    @ Test
    public void testPop() {
        aStackOfInt.push(22);
        assertEquals (new Integer(22),aStackOfInt.pop());
    }
    @Test
    public void testpeek()
    {
        aStackOfInt.push(222);
        assertEquals(new Integer(222),aStackOfInt.peek());
    }


}
```

I'm assuming that the highlighted red codes mean that they are not being executed. If so, I don't know what went wrong. Here are the run result:

[image]

Comment: Can you double check the location of the imported annotations?  That Jupiter package looks strange: Usually the import should be just org.junit.

Comment: Sorry, how do you check that?

Comment: Look in packages org.junit and org.junit.jupiter.api.  The mixed packages might be confusing the test runner.  The test has import org.junit.Before and import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.  See if there is @Before in org.junit.jupiter.api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixin to JUnit API in your tests, JUnit4 and JUnit5.
So, if you want to use the latest one (JUnit 5 which I recommend you), you should import everything from the JUnit5 package: org.junit.jupiter.

So, your test cases would look like this (notice I also did some other changes):

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.util.Stack;

class StackMethodTesting {
    private Stack<Integer> aStackOfInt;

    @BeforeEach
    void initialize()
    {
        aStackOfInt = new Stack<Integer>();
        System.out.println(" a new Stack");
    }

    @Test
    void testpush() {
        Integer value = new Integer(1);
        aStackOfInt.push(value);
        assertTrue(aStackOfInt.peek().equals(value));
    }

    @Test
    void testPop() {
        Integer value = new Integer(22);
        aStackOfInt.push(value);
        assertEquals(value, aStackOfInt.pop());
    }
    @Test
    void testpeek()
    {
        Integer value = new Integer(222);
        aStackOfInt.push(value);
        assertEquals(value, aStackOfInt.peek());
    }


}
```

You can read more about JUnit5 here https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations.

Comment: Also, with JUnit5 you do not need to define as public methods your test cases neither your test classes, you can have them as private (or just remove the public keyword).